# Error: Request failed with status code 403 - Problem with Axios, possible exchange for fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, next.js, fetch

I'm using axios in an application Nextjs where I use the Youtube API and the following error occurred[image: Erro 403]

Below is the code

```
import React from "react";
import youtube from "./api";
import VideoList from "./VideoList";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    videos: [],
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.onTermSubmit("Car");
  }

  onTermSubmit = async (term) => {
    const res = await youtube.get("/search", {
      params: {
        q: term,
      },
    });
    this.setState({ videos: res.data.items });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div>
            <div >
              <VideoList
                videos={this.state.videos}
                
              />
            </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The other

```
import axios from 'axios';

const KEY = "xxxxx";

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3",
  params: {
    part: "snippet",
    maxResults: 16,
    key: KEY,
},

});
```

I would like a tip on how to solve this and if the best solution would be to change from Axios to fetch. Problem is, I don't know how to change from Axios to fetch.

Comment: A `403` status code relates to authorization, so I don't think it's an Axios vs Fetch issue (although it's worth testing to rule that out). Are you sure whatever key you're using is correct and being passed in properly? The correct route? The correct method (e.g., `POST`) and number of required parameters or configuration options? Etc.

Comment: @MarkG The key is correct. I'm new in the area. Within my level of knowledge, I can't identify something wrong in the code

Answer (score 2):

I dont think that is related to package. Because 403 is  forbidden response status code which indicates that the server understands the request but refuses to authorize it. Most likely you pass the wrong api key. If you need to fetch the data with `fetch`, you can write a reusable function:

```
// genre is like video type. for example Productivity
const videos = async (genre) => {
  const YOUTUBE_API_KEY = process.env.YOUTUBE_API_KEY;
  const BASE_URL = "youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3";

  const response = await fetch(
    `https://${BASE_URL}/${genre}&maxResults=25&key=${YOUTUBE_API_KEY}`
  );

  return await response.json();
};
```

this is from [docs](https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/code-samples#javascript)

### Received a 401 or 403 error

If you're getting a 401 or 403 error when testing a sample, it's likely due to a problem with one of the following:

- The API isn't enabled for your project. Review instructions for your API on how to create a project and enable an API.
- You're using the wrong authorization type (API key instead of OAuth 2.0).
- You're using OAuth 2.0, but with too narrow a scope.
- When you set up your API key, you set up restrictions to prevent unauthorized use of your credentials. However, the request isn't meeting those restrictions.

Comment: I did the same mistake. Correcting the credentials worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade to AXIOS 0.26.0

Probably you are using last version automatically.

Related:
https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/4638

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue in Next.js 13 vs Django rest framework and it took me a week to discover that the problem (in my case) came from Axios. I was getting 403 forbidden errors when fetching and uploading files to AWS S3 Bucket. It took me almost five days to solve by just using fetch for my GET and POST requests, instead of Axios. It's unexpected though and I can't explain why. I suspected Axios was setting a wrong default Authentication header, even with the flag: `withCredentials: false.` This only happened in production and not in development.